# SQL table Convert date column to epoch

Tags: mysql, sql, date, timestamp, epoch

I have a table of events which includes a field called `date` in `date` format, so all entries are in the shape of `YYYY-MM-DD`.

Is there any simple solution to (batch) **convert them all into epoch timestamp**, even as a new field (`date2` e.g.) as it has to be an `int`?

There are around 15000 entries inside this table, so I can't do it manually of course.

Comment: What [tag:rdbms] are you using?

Comment: MySQL, it's a part of website database.

Answer (score 1):

The [`unix_timestamp`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp) function does just that:

```
ALTER TABLE mytable ADD COLUMN new_date NUMERIC;

UPDATE mytable SET new_date = UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date);
```

Comment: Oh, right, so simple and I couldn't figure it out, thank you Mureinik!